# migrate from TinyMCE 4 to TinyMCE 5 can not figure out how to do can someone up date for me?

Tags: tinymce, migrate

migrate from TinyMCE 4 to TinyMCE 5 cannot figure out how to do can someone update for me?

some of the download but not working still. I downloaded the file and still cannot find were everything goes. If there is some one that could possibly update for me?